# React Native immersions mode

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-immersive

I want to add immersive mode (fullscreen, without on screen navigation bar) to my React Native app. In the best situation I would have it only when viewing the app in Landscape mode. That way the users will be able to really watch a video in fullscreen.

So I've added this to my mainactivity.java

```js
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
        super.onStart();
    }
```

View is imported from:

```
import android.view.View;
```

When the app "Launches" you see the white loading screen for a second. In that screen I see the immersive mode. But when the React Native app launches it will come back.

Does somebody know the way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Out of the box, the only option you have is to hide or show status bar - [with navigation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html) or manually:

```
import {StatusBar} from "react-native";

componentDidMount() {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true, "fade");
}
```

The true immersive mode can be achieved with extra modules, for example - [react-native-immersive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-immersive).

Answer (score 3):

I've created a package with immersive mode, stickyImmersive mode and more.

react-native-system-navigation-bar

**Install**

```
yarn add react-native-system-navigation-bar
```

or

```
npm install react-native-system-navigation-bar
```

**Links**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-system-navigation-bar

https://github.com/kadiraydinli/react-native-system-navigation-bar